# Java CSV file parsing does not parse empty columns at end

Tags: java, csv

I am parsing a CSV file, however there is one row were the last 9 columns are empty and the string split by comma ignores the remains empty columns.

Here is code to demonstrate this:

```
String s="L2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,108.50,-188.04,,,,,,,,,";
String[] columns = s.split(",");
System.out.println(columns.length);
```

The size of columns is 20, when it should be 29. Any ideas??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

So you need to look at the options for the [other `split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible** and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Emphasis mine.

You need:

```
String[] columns = s.split(",", -1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and answer. That did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

The docs of split says:

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings**
>   will be **discarded**.

`split(String regex)` calls the overloaded `split` method with a limit of 0.That's why you have an array length of 20, all the empty strings after -188.04 are discarded in the resulting array.

If you want to get all the empty trailing strings, you can give a negative limit to say that you want to apply the pattern as many times as possible.

```
String[] columns = s.split(",", -1); //length is 29 there
```

Although it's not hard to parse CSV, you may also want to look about using a CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing manually job of actual CSV parsing library? There is no benefit to trying to skimp on proper job as there are a few good options out there.

- [SuperCSV](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html)
- [Jackson CSV module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv/)

These would also handle aspects of CSV like doubled double-quotes, handling of extra white space and so forth.