# Unable to Parse Final Column from CSV File using Apache Commons CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I have a CSV file with 19 columns in it (the last column is empty). I'm parsing the file via Apache Commons CSV. When I execute:

```
System.out.println("csvRecord.toString() = " + csvRecord.toString());
```

I get the following output:

```
csvRecord.toString() = CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={Amount=6, ID=2, UID=4, Address=5, Carrier=17, CPL=14, F=12, GC=13, PIT=9, PP=11, PCIT=10, PT=1, SPI=3, SPI1=8, ST=7, Status=16, SOI=0, TN=18, TP=15}, recordNumber=6, values=[FB, S13 Wood Carving, B07, AG, bis, FB, 44.8, PE, AG XXXXXXX47, UNKNOWN, 39.95, 1.6, 4.1, , -2.2068006148899633, -0.46425251802390777, COMPLETED, US]]
```

As you can see, the last column `TN=18` (which is actually column 19 when counting from one) is included in output of `toString()` method in the `mapping` section (but not in the `values` section).

However, when I convert `csvRecord` to map via the following code:

```
Map<String, String> csvRecordMap = csvRecord.toMap();
```

The last column is no longer present. And when I execute:

```
if (csvRecordMap.containsKey("TN"))
```

It returns false.

Based on my testing I've noticed that the `toMap()` method will not include an empty column if there are no *non empty* columns after it (even if the column is actually present in CSV file). If a column is empty but there are *non empty* columns after it, then it will be included in return value of `toMap()` method.

How can I force parser to return all columns -- either via `toMap()` method or by somehow extracting it from `csvRecord` directly as it is obviously present as shown in `toString()` method ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through and add the missing names:

```
Map<String, String> map = csvRecord.toMap();
for (String name : csvParser.getHeaderNames())
    map.putIfAbsent(name, "");
```

*Demo*

```
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader();
try (CSVParser csvParser = csvFormat.parse(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.txt")))) {
    System.out.println(csvParser.getHeaderNames());
    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
        System.out.println(csvRecord);
        System.out.println("  toMap(): " + csvRecord.toMap());

        Map<String, String> map = csvRecord.toMap();
        for (String name : csvParser.getHeaderNames())
            map.putIfAbsent(name, "");
        System.out.println("  fixed  : " + map);
    }
}
```

*test.txt*

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2
1
1,
1,,
1,,,
,,,4,,,
```

*Output (with `commons-csv-1.7.jar`)*

```
[A, B, C, D]
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=1, values=[1, 2, 3, 4]]
  toMap(): {A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4}
  fixed  : {A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4}
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=2, values=[1, 2, 3]]
  toMap(): {A=1, B=2, C=3}
  fixed  : {A=1, B=2, C=3, D=}
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=3, values=[1, 2]]
  toMap(): {A=1, B=2}
  fixed  : {A=1, B=2, C=, D=}
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=4, values=[1]]
  toMap(): {A=1}
  fixed  : {A=1, B=, C=, D=}
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=5, values=[1, ]]
  toMap(): {A=1, B=}
  fixed  : {A=1, B=, C=, D=}
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=6, values=[1, , ]]
  toMap(): {A=1, B=, C=}
  fixed  : {A=1, B=, C=, D=}
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=7, values=[1, , , ]]
  toMap(): {A=1, B=, C=, D=}
  fixed  : {A=1, B=, C=, D=}
CSVRecord [comment='null', recordNumber=8, values=[, , , 4, , , ]]
  toMap(): {A=, B=, C=, D=4}
  fixed  : {A=, B=, C=, D=4}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to force toMap() method to include empty columns? I suspect the issue stems from similar issue discussed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29440357 No?

Comment: @S.O.S *"Is there a way ... ?"* Yes, modify the code, it is open-source, so you have full access to it.